# Calculating Average based on Condition in SAP HANA GRAPHICAL VIEW

Tags: sql, hana

I need to calculate total average as well as average for each value of `ColumnD`, divided by number of unique values in `ColumnA`:

```
ColumnA   ColumnB  ColumnC  ColumnD
     A         10       xyz      Ab
     A         20       def      Ab
     A         5        mno      Xy
     B         10       pqr      Ab
     B         40       abc      Xy
     C         10       uvw      Xy
```

Total Average (divided by unique `ColumnA`):

```
(10+20+5+10+40+10)/3= 31.66
```

Now I need Average for `ColumnD = 'Ab'`:

```
(10+20+10)/2
```

Average for `ColumnD = 'Xy'`:

```
(5+40+10)/3
```

I made Calculated Column in HANA:

Counter-> CA_Count on ColumnA(to get unique Count)
CA_Avg ->

```
ColumnB/CA_Count
```

for Avg of Ab:
CA_AVG_Ab :

```
if(ColumnD='Ab',CA_Avg,0)
```

but this Value is not coming correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To model different aggregation levels in CVs you need to model separate data flows leading into separate aggregation nodes. 
The output of these agg. nodes can then be joined together (outer join, obviously).

Comment: So you mean to say, w need to create 2 different CV's for Ab and Xy and then join them?? as my above logic is working, but if we apply filter on multiple values of ColumnC, the output will be wrong!

Comment: That's not what I wrote. You model both (all) aggregations in the same CV and feed all of them the same data from the very same projection node. You end up with a single projection node at the bottom that fans out into multiple aggregation nodes, that then get `join`ed or `union`ed together leading into a single final projection again.